# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(t^{2})dt$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(t^{2})dt$ using Cauchy‘s theorem

Tags: cauchy-integral-formula, singular-integrals

I have learnt several ways to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(t^{2})dt$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(t^{2})dt$ before. Now I need to evaluate them by integrating $f(z)=e^{\frac{z^{2}}{2}}$ along the follow contour[image: contour]

I can show that
$$
\lim_{R\rightarrow +\infty}\int_{C_{1}(R)}f(z)dz=-i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{R\rightarrow +\infty}\int_{C_{2}(R)}f(z)dz=(1+i)\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(t^{2})dt+(-1+i)\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(t^{2})dt.
$$

However, I found it difficult to show
$$
\lim_{R\rightarrow +\infty}\int_{C_{3}(R)}f(z)dz=0.
$$
Any advice will be helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: $C_3(R):[0, R] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $C_3(R)(t) := R-t+iR$. Just plug in, estimate $\lvert \int \rvert$ by pulling the absolute value into the integral and use $\lvert \exp(z) \rvert = \exp(\mathrm{Re}(z) )$

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/q/105457/454

Comment: In this way, I think  I need to deal with $\lim_{R\rightarrow +\infty}\int_{0}^{R}e^{\frac{t^{2}}{2}-Rt}dt$. How can I estimate this integral?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write the integral on the segment $C_3$ as
$$\left|\int_{C_3}\right|=\left|-\int_0^{R} e^{(x+iR)^2/2}\right|dx\le\int_0^{R}e^{\Re(x^2/2+iRx-R^2/2)}dx=\frac{1}{e^{R^2/2}}\int_0^{R}e^{x^2/2}dx.$$